# Как прикрутить скриптинг Python к приложению, написанному на c++?

Tags: c++, python

Есть приложение, написанное с нуля на c++ и Qt 5. Нужно добавить скриптинг на Python в стиле 3ds max, то есть так:

1. Набираем скрипт во встроенном в приложение редакторе.
2. Сохраняем его.
3. Нажимаем кнопку **Evaluate** и выполяем скрипт.

Выполняем так, чтобы иметь доступ из одного скрипта ко всей объектной модели приложения. Я нашёл уроки, но ситуация плачевная: требуется extension - чтобы приложение изначально было написано на Python. В противном случае совет один: берётся метод на c++ и с нужным числом аргументов вызывается такой же метод на Python, при этом кроме аргументов я в Python ничего не имею. Как из встроенного Python получить доступ ко всей объектной модели приложения?

Comment: Если из Python к существующему c++ коду получить доступ хочется,(*питон встраивается путём расширения*), то [`pybind11` можно пробовать](http://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html). Подойдёт любой способ, который расширения для CPython позволяет писать, например,  [Cython](http://cython.org/), [cffi (последнее только C вызывает)](https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#goals).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Питон в приложение встраивается примерно так:

```
#include <Python.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);  /* optional but recommended */
  Py_Initialize();
  PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime\n"
                     "print 'Today is',ctime(time())\n");
  Py_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

Больше - в официальной документации https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html

Comment: Разве это дает доступ к объектам плюсовым?

Comment: Я это знаю. Я уже встроил. Я упёрся в вопрос, которым кончается мой пост...

Comment: @VladimirGamalian напишите - даст. Если у автора Qt - через MOC можно много чего получить.

Comment: @IliaIvanov автоматически ничего не будет, распознать кучу классов в автоматическом режиме не реально. Используйте MOC, он вполне позволяет манипулировать объектами Qt. Но это уже совсем другой вопрос, к питону отношения не имеющий...

Comment: В общем, всё понятно, зря я спрашивал. Я не хотел автоматически, я хотел любым способом. Пошёл разбираться самостоятельно...

Comment: @IliaIvanov По ссылке выше описано как расширять функциональность встроенного в приложение Питона вашим сишным кодом. Второй вариант - шаманство с MOC, раз у вас Qt.

Comment: Я нашёл ответ в документации. Это называется "расширение встроенного Python". Требуется список функций и ещё немного кода - дописать функции в таблицу модуля. Примерно так: https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html#extending-embedded-python. И на этом считаю дискуссию оконченной.

Comment: @IliaIvanov Вы не поверите, но про "Extending Embedded Python" есть и по приведенной мной ссылке.